# Contact Editor Extension "Custom Data" error

Tags: profile, extension, duplicate-contacts

We installed the [Contact Editor Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-editor) to change profiles from an Individual to an Organization and vice versa. We are getting an error that says, "The contact has custom data that is not valid for the new type." when attempting to change a profile from Individual -> Organization. We have tried disabling any custom fields that are set for Individuals only and are still getting the error.

Has anyone found a solution to this? We aren't sure what custom data it is getting caught up on.

(Using version 7.4.30)

Comment: What custom data have you added? I believe the issue would be your own custom fields. Do you have a lot of them? Each custom field has a record type they are associated with. It's shown in the "Used for" column of the page at Administer->Customize data and screens->Custom fields.

Comment: We have quite a few custom fields set to Individual only. I don't see a way to switch those when I go to Settings for the custom field sets. Is there a way to adjust them?

Comment: there is no way that I know of in the web interface. Even moving the field to a new field group is not possible if the type doesn't match. It may be possible in the database, but I'm not brave enough to try. You could try clearing the custom fields in one of the individual records and then seeing if you can change the contact type.